# get cascaded style in webkit

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

How can i get the cascaded style (not computed) for an element? 
say i have an element with the matched CSS rule width: 50%;

I want to get the string "width: 50%"

```
style.cssText
```

only works for inline style

I got as far as using

```
elm = document.getElementById("myElm");
rules = elms.ownerDocument.defaultView.getMatchedCSSRules(elm, '');
```

now i have a list of all CSS rules relevant  to this element, but how can i know which one is the rule that was matched?

is the order rules in `rules` relevant to the "cascading" of styles? i've done some simple tests and I appears that that is the case but i can't really be sure.

I dont need a cross platform solution, but it has to work with webkit browser and native JS.

Comment: Why can't you work with the computed style? It sounds like that's what you need. And yes, order of rules matter. As long as the selectors are the same, that is, they don't have different specificities.

Comment: in doing some style manipulation and in order to do it correctly  important for me to know were the style "came from"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you need something like this:

`var casWidth = ( $element.width() / $parentRelativeElement.width() ) * 100`

Comment: I actually need the original css string, if the style was set as a percentage or "auto" or any other special  value

Comment: [late reply] it doesn't matters if the css width isn't fixed. Jquery will take your current width and convert it to pixels.